# If I return a value inside a using block in a method, does the using dispose of the object before the return?

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable

I'm going through some old C#.NET code in an ASP.NET application making sure that all **SqlConnections** are wrapped in **using** blocks.

I know that **using** is the same as **try** / **finally** where it disposes of the object in the **finally** no matter what happens in the **try**. If I have a method that returns a value inside the **using**, even though execution leaves the method when it returns, does it still call **.Dispose()** on my object before/during/after it's returning?

```
public static SqlCommand getSqlCommand(string strSql, string strConnect){
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnect))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = GetSqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = strSql;
        return cmd;
    }
}
```

**Update:** The accepted answer is the one I think best answers my question but note that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313196/if-i-return-a-value-inside-a-using-block-in-a-method-does-the-using-dispose-of-t/2313223#2313223) caught the stupidity of this code, that I'm returning a command that uses a disposed connection! :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it will still call dispose.

Run this very simple console application top verify:

```
   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestMethod();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static string TestMethod()
        {
            using (new Me())
            {
                return "Yes";
            }
        }
    }

    class Me : IDisposable
    {
        #region IDisposable Members

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Disposed");
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

Yes.  It will dispose of your object.  This will actually cause a problem in your code, since the `SqlCommand` being returned is dependent on the `SqlConnection`, which will be Disposed of prior to the control flow returning to your caller.

You can, however, use delegates to work around this.  A good pattern to handle this is to rewrite your method like so:

```
public static SqlCommand ProcessSqlCommand(string strSql, string strConnect, Action<SqlCommand> processingMethod)
{ 
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnect)) 
    { 
        con.Open(); 
        SqlCommand cmd = GetSqlCommand(); 
        cmd.Connection = con; 
        cmd.CommandText = strSql; 
        processingMethod(cmd); 
    } 
}
```

You can then call this like:

```
ProcessSqlCommand(sqlStr, connectStr, (cmd) =>
    {
        // Process the cmd results here...
    });
```

Comment: wow, good catch! thanks. this method isn't used in many places (and is old) so I will probably just remove it and create the commands where I need them