# When I use a using object should I dispose this object before exiting the using block?

Tags: c#, .net

When I use a using clause on an object should I dispose this object before exiting the using block?

```
            using (var transaction = TransactionUtils.CreateTransactionScope())
            {
                try
                {
                    _entity.Save(entity);
                    transaction.Complete();
                }
                catch // or better finally
                {
                    transaction.Dispose(); // Is this try-catch usefull?
                    throw;
                }
            }
```

Note :  [A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2313196/196526) has already been asked but I find the example and the answers strange.

Comment: You refer to previous question in general, could you provide a link or links?  What about them do you find confusing, what do they say?

Comment: This is well explained in the [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is redundant to dispose the object.

```
using (ResourceType resource = CreateResource())
{
    DoStuffWith(resource);
}
```

is equivalent to

```
ResourceType resource = CreateResource();

try
{
    DoStuffWith(resource);
}
finally
{    
    if (resource != null)
    {
        ((IDisposable)resource).Dispose();
    }
}
```

For non-nullable value types the null-check is omitted and `dynamic` is handled slightly different, too. See 8.13 in the [C# Language Specification](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=199552) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Your transaction will be disposed automatically when exiting the using block.

This works under the hood like a try-finally block.

So there is no need to dispose the transaction manual from your code