# should I really dispose my object before exiting the scope of my method?

Tags: c#, .net

I get a **CA2000** error from my code analysis asking me to dispose my objects before exiting the scope

> Dispose objects before losing scope   In method
>   'MyMethod(Guid?)', call
>   System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'person' before all references to
>   it are out of scope.

I'm surprised of this rule because I thought the dispose was automatically run when exiting the scope. Note :  [A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2313196/196526) has already been asked and confirm my opinion to not force the dispose procedure.

What happens if I don't dispose my object and i don't use it in a using instruction?

Comment: Where did you get that quote?  Out of context, it doesn't seem to mean much; just wrap your method in a `using` statement.

Comment: Post your code. Only using `using` will call dispose.

Comment: It depends on the definition of Person. That it implements IDisposable suggests it should be in a using block.

Comment: Yes Person implements IDisposable. But what if I dont write the using or dispose my objet. Will my object live forever in the memory ?

Comment: Why "of course". Is there something in it that REALLY needs disposal? And Dispose will NOT be called automatically. The only thing called automatically is the finalizer (if implemented) and that will `usually` call dispose. But only when the GC starts a collection - which might be NEVER or OFTEN during your app's lifetime.

Comment: @MiserableVariable: Actually, you can call dispose on a class that implements `IDisposable` anytime you want to. The `using` statement is the way to go, but if for whatever reason someone did not want to take advantage of compiler magic they could simply use a `try { ... } finally { //Dispose }` ... That's what using statements compile into anyways.

Comment: @m-y I should have said `using` will call it automatically, at the end of the block. Though I would not call `dispose` in a `using` block myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought the dispose was automatically run when exiting the scope.

Not *any* scope, only a `using` block scope. Exiting a method is not the same as exiting a `using` block.

If an object implements `IDisposable`, then you should always dispose it manually or via a `using` block. It is up to you when to do this, based on the structure of your code.

Answer (score 4):

Dispose is never called automatically. You must call it explicitly, or use the 'using' keyword
At least, if you don't dispose your object, it may be done by the garbage collector but only if you implement the correct patern.

Answer (score 3):

If you have wrapped your object inside the `using` statement you are ok, because it will be translated to.

```
try{
    var myObject = new MyObject();
}finally{
    myObject.Dispose();
}
```

*Update*

If you do not dispose your object it *'might stay in memory forever'* keeping the attached resources. But might not. It depends on garbage collector when it comes around tries to clear it. But beware GC is **only able to clear managed resources**.

Look here for similar question: [What happens if I don't call Dispose on the pen object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267729/what-happens-if-i-dont-call-dispose-on-the-pen-object)

Answer (score 1):

Dispose not called when object goes out of scope. In many scenarios it will be called when garbage collect the object (when implemented Finalizer and Dispose called in it).