# Is is right to return a method inside a "using(object that implements iDisposable)" statment?

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable, using

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If I return a value inside a using block in a method, does the using dispose of the object before the return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313196/if-i-return-a-value-inside-a-using-block-in-a-method-does-the-using-dispose-of)

I have this code (simplyfied):

```
bool method1()
{
      using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connString))
            {
                bool b = false;

                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    b = true;

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    b = false;
                }
                finally
                {
                    con.Close();
                    return b;
                }                
            }
}
```

I return before the closing curly bracket of the "using" statment. Does my object "con" gets Disposed anyway? Is is better to use the following code?:

```
bool method1()
{
      bool b = false;
      using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connString))
            {
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    b = true;

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    b = false;
                }
                finally
                {
                    con.Close();                    
                }                
            }

        return b;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`using` expands into somewhat more complex with  additional `if` statement like

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connString)
try
{
    con.Open();
}
finally
{
    // Check for a null resource.
    if (con != null)
        // Call the object's Dispose method.
        ((IDisposable)con).Dispose();
}
```

So in your example you might get `NullReferenceException` in finally block.

So if you want to return the status of operation and Dispose and object, I suggest to use this code snippet

```
using(OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connString))
{
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        return true;
    }catch(OleDbException ex)
    {
        //log error
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I chose this one as the answer because it is the most accurate to my specific case AND I didn't notice I could get a NullReferenceException in some scenarios. Thanks!

Comment: please note not to catch `Exception` in catch block. Just catch specific `OleDbException` exceptions. But event in this case, I would consider making method `void` and not to return some flag. It makes exception for exceptional cases, not for normal flow of logic.

Answer (score 4):

The whole point of the `using` statement is that it automates the disposal of an object, even if an unhandled exception is thrown from within the using block.

Therefore, once your code exits the using block, whether it's returning or otherwise, then the object being 'used' us disposed.

Comment: Note also that because of this, you don't need to call `Close()` explicitly as you have done. If you decompile `OleDbConnection` you will see that Dispose calls Close

Comment: @Rhumborl: thanks for the tip. I came from an unmanaged world (VB6 C++), so I easily get confused with the Garbage Collector stuff.

Comment: Y3L1NNa - You get +1 for atleast using using. Forget most of all you knew about VB and C++ and let C#/NET stand omn its own accord. Later, you can compare and appreciate both VB and C++, once you get used to the 'managed code, managed data' paradigm. Happy Coding

Answer (score 2):

It is completely safe to return during a using statement due to the .NET magic of automatically handling disposal of objects. The whole idea is that you don't have to think about how you exit out of the using block, you just know that when you leave it the object will be disposed correctly. Because of such, your example could be simplified to this:

```
bool method1()
{
    using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connString))
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }          
    }
}
```

con.Close() can be removed as well as it is automatically called by the disposal.

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421797/what-really-happens-in-a-try-return-x-finally-x-null-statement) if you want to see what happens under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

there is no difference between two code sections; `con` object will be disposed in both examples.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example you set a temporary variable and return that.

About the return in the finally: What happens after compilation is that you branch to the end of the method and then return a temporary variable.

E.g. the results is exactly the same. Just for clarity I would personally prefer the first one, because it resembles what happens more exactly.